# UITableViewCell not showing first MPMoviePlayerController video on the cell in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uitableview

I am trying to add video on `UITableViewCell` the video is adding perfectly but the problem is that when I add second video the first cell on `UITableViewCell` is got black and second cell showing video.

I want all my cell showing video first frame(video picture)

But it is showing only last one(Last cell)

Then I add `UIButton` to play every cell video it is working perfectly.

My Problem is that I want all my cell showing video first frame(video picture) on every `UITableViewCell`.

But problem is if only one cell add then it is showing video first picture perfectly. Then I click button and its started video perfectly but when I add second video the first one got black and second one work perfectly.

Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (indexPath.section==0) {


   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"listData"];

   if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];
      cell.selectedBackgroundView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@".png"] ]; 
        cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@".png"] ];

         [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];


       UILabel * lbl =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(330, 80, 135, 41)];
       lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
       lbl.text = @"Play Video Here";
      [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl];





       NSInteger x = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]  integerForKey:@"cellRowNumber"];
       NSLog(@"x is %d",x);

       if (x<1) {

           x = 0;
       }


       NSURL* url = [UIAppDelegate.videoUrlsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

       NSLog(@"selected tableview row is %d",indexPath.row);

      NSInteger p = indexPath.row ;
       NSLog(@"P is %d",p);




       secView2 =[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(84,5,600,170)];
       secView2.tag = indexPath.row;
       secView2.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
       [cell.contentView addSubview:secView2];



       moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
       moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,600,170);
       moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
       [moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
       moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = NO;
       [secView2 addSubview:moviePlayer.view];


       playBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
       playBtn.tag = indexPath.row;
       playBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,600,170);
       [playBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
       playBtn.tag = indexPath.row;
       [playBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(didButtonTouchUpInside:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
       [secView2 addSubview:playBtn];



   }


   // moviePlayer.contentURL = [UIAppDelegate.videoUrlsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    //[self.moviePlayer pause];
    return cell;

    }

else {

// Nothing

       }

//cell.textLabel.text = [UIAppDelegate.youTubeUrlsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;


 return cell;

    }
 }


-(void)didButtonTouchUpInside:(id)sender{


UIButton *btn = (UIButton *) sender;
CGRect buttonFrameInTableView = [btn convertRect:btn.bounds toView:table];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [table indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonFrameInTableView.origin];

NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);



secView =[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 960)];
secView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:secView];


NSURL* url = [UIAppDelegate.videoUrlsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

// Now set up the movie player controller and play the movie.
player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: url];
[[player view] setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 50, 768, 910)];  // frame must match parent view
[secView addSubview: [player view]];
[player play];



//btn_hideSecview = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btn_hideSecview =[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 45)];
btn_hideSecview.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
// btn_hideSecview.frame = CGRectMake(600, 0, 70, 45);
[btn_hideSecview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[btn_hideSecview addTarget:self action:@selector(method_Hide_Secview) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[secView addSubview:btn_hideSecview];
}
```

Any idea or suggestions would be highly welcome.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you have created "secView2" and "moviePlayer" as local properties, that means you use only one instance of these classes. For each invoke of table delegate method cellForRowAtIndexPath - create new object of MoviePlayer and UIView. If you need access outside of that delegate, prepare some DataSource NSMutableArray which will store that instances.

MPMoviePlayerController  * newPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

and

UIView *secView2 =[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(84,5,600,170)];